# Is Basic Authentication over HTTPS secure?

Tags: authentication, basic-authentication

We have Keycloak Installation and we provide Basic Authentication i.e Username and Password to customer for API Access over Internet.

What are security risks of this approach?

What I understand from many articles and even mozilla documentation that if Basic Authentication is on HTTPS then no issue.

Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication

Comment:  https://security.stackexchange.com/q/215517/719

Answer (score 3):

The solution is secure, but it limits your options. E.g. you won't be able to implement two-factor authentication and all your services that handle the request will have to call the user database in order to verify credentials, which will happen on every request.